# "Build a PC", "assemble a PC", or something else?

Tags: word-choice, verbs, collocation

When you have all the parts of a PC and you need to connect them into a working PC, which is the appropriate verb to describe this action: *build*, *assemble* or something else?

Comment: I would say _assemble_, but there may be some specialist term used in the industry.

Comment: Both build and assemble are common, but the latter is more industrial-sounding than the former. I built my last PC myself from parts I got online, but I might work in a computer store assembling units.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To me `building a PC` is buying all the actual components (RAM, SSD, sound card, screen, etc) and putting them all into a case to make a computer. Whereas, `assembling a PC` just sounds like unpacking one from the box and plugging everything into the right port.

Comment: Spoken as a true hardware geek/connoisseur. Only an actual hardware geek like you would understand why yours is the most appropriate answer.

Comment: I wouldn't call unpacking a machine and connecting monitors and keyboards and such things ‘assembling’ it—that's just connecting it (or something like that). I'd say your first sentence is spot on, though: what makes _building_ a PC is the fact that you choose, find, buy, and procure the individual parts yourself. Once you have all the parts, putting them together into a box is the bit I'd call _assembling_ it. If you only assemble a machine, it is implied that the parts are already there for you, they just need to be put together.

Answer (score 1):

You *assemble* a kit into a PC; you *build* a PC of choice configuration from the parts as needed.

So, decide if you want it *a la mode* or *a la carte*.

Answer (score 0):

When "building" a PC, you're just assembling a pre-produced, unique, specialized and working parts into a working rig. The most logical word choice here is "assemble".

Building would imply making those working parts from scratch, but that's what factories do.

Comment: But we still speak of people building houses, when all of the 'parts' (bricks, joists, roof tiles, floor tiles, carpets, etc.) are made elsewhere.

Comment: The way I personally see it: Computer parts (motherboard, Graphics card, processor, fans) are highly specialized parts with many components themselves. A brick is just a brick, not unique from other bricks in any way. You're not merely putting bricks together, there are processes behind it. Putting a GPU in its place and plugging it in doesnt seem like building to me. Just my view on this.

Answer (score -1):

**Assemble** is the verb you need to use, as you are putting together all the parts.
All PC companies, and even the ones who custom-make them, use the word assemble.It is the accepted industry term.

**Assemble:**
fit together the separate component parts of (a machine or other object).
"my new machine is being assembled and my old one dismantled"

(Google dictionary)

Comment: This is not correct: ‘assemble’ is not the only choice here; it is in fact the inferior choice in some contexts.

Comment: "Assembling a PC" is the most commonly used phrase that I have heard.Also,even when the parts are bought from different companies and put together, it is called assembling.